# Can't install php mongodb driver into php

Tags: php, mongodb, iis, driver

I've followed the steps and placed the `php_mongo.dll` file into my `C:\Program Files(x86)\PHP\v5.6\ext` and added`"extension = php_mongo.dll"` into my `php.ini`. However, it wouldn't show up when i `echo phpinfo();` I had tried `$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017");` and `MongoDB\Driver\Manager`instead of MongoClient, those class are not found. Can't seems to find any solution anywhere. Please help, thank you.

Comment: Did you init your `package.json` and install `mongodb and
    mongoose` ?

Comment: did you restart  apache server ?

Comment: Yes, I did restart my IIS Server.